# SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17028 Invalid request fields in play_integrity_token - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, token, sha256, sha1

E/FirebaseAuth(12806): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17028 Invalid request fields in play_integrity_token
D/FirebaseAuth(12806): Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +994503731324, error - This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ Invalid request fields in play_integrity_token ]
I/flutter (12806): This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ Invalid request fields in play_integrity_token ][image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 7):

in my case it happened when I was using the emulator, and tried to log in with a real number. You can use test phone numbers instead
[Firebase auth docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth#setup)

> Note; Phone number sign-in is only available for use on real devices and the web. To test your authentication flow on device emulators, please see Testing.

-----------------------------------------

addition: Sometimes wipe emulator data helps.

Comment: they should mention this in logcat :D